# android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

im trying to make a splash screen, the codes showing no errors, build succesfully, but when it started,it shows this message at the apps

[image]

and when i check the log on android monitor, it show these messages

```
08-07 05:41:23.709 16344-16344/com.android.andika.soundsmart E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.android.andika.soundsmart.SplashS has leaked window DecorView@e044f4c[] that was originally added here
                                                                                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:418)
                                                                                  at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:331)
                                                                                  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
                                                                                  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:329)
                                                                                  at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:1112)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6723)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2662)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2766)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1507)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6236)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:891)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:781)
```

this is the code from my splashscreen class

```
public class SplashS extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    int status = 0;
    int proses = 0;
    Handler handle = new Handler();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_s);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("SPLASHSREEN");
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        ab.hide();

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.tunggu);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(status<100){
                    status = loading();
                    handle.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressBar.setProgress(status);

                        }
                    });
                }
                handle.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent pindah = new Intent(SplashS.this,MenuS.class);
                        startActivity(pindah);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            }

            private int loading() {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(45);
                }
                catch(InterruptedException ie){
                    ie.printStackTrace();
                }
                return ++proses;
            }
        }).start();
    }

}
```

i debug the app via an android phone with android N 7.1 OS.

i'll appreciate any answer, advice, or response. thanks :)

Comment: It seems to be an issue with Android N while using native libraries. Are you using any such libraries?

Comment: i'm new to android programming, so any libraries i used was default libraries, not a custom one. But, my phone has custom Android ROM from unofficial developer.

Comment: Try running the app on a separate device with Android N from Google itself. The issue was fixed as Ahmed Aboelyazeed mentioned officially by Google. See if the app works on that device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that error related to showing dialog where the activity is dismissed , but your code does not showing any dialogs so check if you are using 3rd party libraries which can do that